# Are linux VMs installed on Windows Host in VirtualBox "real" linux?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox on my Windows 7 machine, and recently installed a Redhat linux VM. I'm planning to learn linux programming with some low-level stuff, such as kernel function calls and assembly.

My question is: is my Redhat VM a "real" linux environment for my purpose? I guess that whatever I do in the VM is done in a "linux simulator" in VirtualBox, and under the hood the "linux simulator" still does its job using functionalities provided by the Windows host (e.g. Windows function calls). Is this true?

Comment: For most practical purposes, there is no difference in what you do in a VirtualBox Linux install and a bare metal install. For details please ask on http://superuser.com, because this is a programming related site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should dual boot linux instead of VM because not only it saves resources ("Prevent Computer from going slow") But also give you better functionality and hardware support

Edit:
 and you can also use Live Cd(also usb)

Comment: You should not answer questions that do not belong on this SO site.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox is not a "Linux simulator", it is a "computer simulator". OS selections within such an simulator are for the purpose of deciding which virtual devices to make visible, and not for running a different simulator "core".

Comment: so what exactly happens when e.g. in the linux VM i step through an assembly instruction in the debugger? Does such linux VM suffice for the purpose of programming in linux assembly?

Comment: The assembly instruction is stepped through. Neither the program nor the debugger care that they are being run on a simulated computer.

Comment: OK then practically there's no difference from a real linux box (for my purpsose). Thanks.